# Sorting (or partially sorting) a list of objects based on a specific attribute

Tags: python, sorting, heapq

**Problem**

I have a list of objects. Each object has two attributes: *"score"* and *"coordinates"*. I need to find the largest **N** objects of the list based on the `score` attribute. The main problem I'm having is sorting the objects using **only** the `score` attribute. Sorting can be partial. I'm only interested in the **N** largest objects.

**Current Solution**

My current approach is not the most elegant nor the most efficient. The idea is to create a `dictionary` of object `indices` and their `score`, then sort the list of scores and use the `dictionary` to index the objects that yielded the largest scores.

These are the steps:

1. Create a list of `scores`. Each element of the list corresponds to an object. *That is, the first entry is the score of the first object, the second entry is the score of the second object, and so on.*
2. Create a `dictionary` using the object's `scores` as `key` and object `index` as `value`.
3. Order the score list using a `heapq` to get the `N` largest objects.
4. Use the `dictionary` to get those objects that have the largest `scores`.
5. Create a new `list` with only the `N` largest-score objects.

**Code Snippets**

This is my sorting function:

```
import random
import heapq


# Gets the N objects with the largest score:
def getLargest(N, objects):
    # Set output objects:
    outobjects = objects

    # Get the total of objects in list:
    totalobjects = len(objects)

    # Check if the total number of objects is bigger than the N requested
    # largest objects:

    if totalobjects > N:

        # Get the "score" attributes from all the objects:
        objectScores = [o.score for o in objects]

        # Create a dictionary with the index of the objects and their score.
        # I'm using a dictionary to keep track of the largest scores and
        # the objects that produced them:
        objectIndices = range(totalobjects)
        objectDictionary = dict(zip(objectIndices, objectScores))

        # Get the N largest objects based on score:
        largestObjects = heapq.nlargest(N, objectScores)
        print(largestObjects)

        # Prepare the output list of objects:
        outobjects = [None] * N

        # Look for those objects that produced the
        # largest score:
        for k in range(N):
            # Get current largest object:
            currentLargest = largestObjects[k]
            # Get its original position on the keypoint list:
            position = objectScores.index(currentLargest)
            # Index the corresponding keypoint and store it
            # in the output list:
            outobjects[k] = objects[position]

    # Done:
    return outobjects
```

This snippet generates `100` random objects used to test my method. The final loop prints the `N = 3` randomly-generated objects with the largest `score`:

```
# Create a list with random objects:
totalObjects = 100
randomObjects = []


# Test object class:
class Object(object):
    pass


# Generate a list of random objects
for i in range(totalObjects):
    # Instance of objects:
    tempObject = Object()
    # Set the object's random score
    random.seed()
    tempObject.score = random.random()
    # Set the object's random coordinates:
    tempObject.coordinates = (random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(0, 5))
    # Store object into list:
    randomObjects.append(tempObject)

# Get the 3 largest objects sorted by score:
totalLargestObjects = 3
largestObjects = getLargest(totalLargestObjects, randomObjects)

# Print the filtered objects:
for i in range(len(largestObjects)):
    # Get the current object in the list:
    currentObject = largestObjects[i]
    # Get its score:
    currentScore = currentObject.score
    # Get its coordinates as a tuple (x,y)
    currentCoordinates = currentObject.coordinates
    # Print the info:
    print("object: " + str(i) + " score: " + str(currentScore) + " x: " + str(
        currentCoordinates[0]) + " y: " + str(currentCoordinates[1]))
```

My current method gets the job done, but there has to be a more *pythonic* (more vectorized) way of achieving the same thing. My background is mostly C++, I'm still learning Python. Any feedback is welcome.

**Additional info**

Initially, I was looking for something similar to C++'s [`std:: nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). It appears this functionality is somewhat provided in Python by NumPy's [`partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html). Unfortunately, while `std::nth_element` supports a predicate for custom ordering, NumPy's `partition` does not. I ended up using a `heapq`, which does the job nicely and sorts in the desired order, but I don't know the optimal way to sort based on one attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tuple is what you needed**. Instead of storing scores in a heap, stores a tuple of `(score, object)` in the heap. It will try to compare by the score and return a list of tuples which you can use to retrieve the original objects. This will save you extra steps to retrieve objects by their scores:

```
heapq.nlargest(3, ((obj.score, obj) for obj in randomObjects))
# [(0.9996643881256989, <__main__.Object object at 0x155f730>), (0.9991398955041872, <__main__.Object object at 0x119e928>), (0.9858047551444177, <__main__.Object object at 0x15e38c0>)]
```

For a real world example: https://akuiper.com/console/g6YuNa_1WClp

Or as @shriakhilc commented, use `key` parameter in `heapq.nlargest` to specify you want to compare by score:

```
heapq.nlargest(3, randomObjects, lambda o: o.score)
```

Comment: `heapq.nlargest` accepts a key function, so it is possible to do `largestObjects = heapq.nlargest(totalLargestObjects, randomObjects, key=lambda o: o.score)` and do away with both the method and tuples

Comment: @shriakhilc Ahh really good point. Forgot about that :)

Comment: @Psidom Man, this is excellent! Thanks a lot, Psidom and @shriakhilc!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use sorted python native method + lambda function. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

Basically, this is what you can have:

```
myList = [
  {score: 32, coordinates: [...]},
  {score: 12, coordinates: [...]},
  {score: 20, coordinates: [...]},
  {score: 8, coordinates: [...]},
  {score: 40, coordinates: [...]},
]

# Sort by score DESCENDING
mySortedList = sorted(myList, key=lambda element: element['score'], reverse=True)

# Retrieve top 3 results
myTopResults = mySortedList[0:3]
```